# Sorting and filtering is not working in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Below snippet of code i have added for filtering and sorting the datastore records,

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Filter propertyFilter =
                new FilterPredicate("stockId", FilterOperator.EQUAL, stockId);
        com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query q = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query("MessageEntity")
                .setFilter(propertyFilter).addSort("messageId", SortDirection.ASCENDING);

         List<Entity> results=
                    datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(10));
```

if i remove

> addSort("messageId", SortDirection.ASCENDING)

Query works well as expected but if add above line App engine does not give any response. Here am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because your property "messageId" is not indexed. You can either make it indexed (and re-save all existing entities), or sort the results of the query in your own code.

Sorting results in code maybe a better option as it does not require an extra composite index which takes more space that you have to pay for.

Comment: i have added @index on the messageId of MessageEntity, is it not enough  ?

Comment: It will only apply to new entities. You have to re-save existing entities for them to be re-indexed.

Comment: ohhh...Thank you...i will check again. For indexing i was checkinghttps://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-datastore-indexes-with-index-yaml where exacting i need to put this in my project and any pattern suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use composite indexes. check out this page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities

Moreover if you check your log appengine provides you a really clear explanation of the problem plus it also suggests you the right composite index to add to you datastore.indexes.xml